# How to re-populate check box in edit form using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So far I know how to repopulate the form input and checkbox

It looks like that:

```
value="<?= set_value('rank') ?>" for input
```

and

```
 <?= set_checkbox('is_default', '1'); ?> for checkbox
```

The problem is, how about in the edit form:

The input value is sofar ok:

```
value="<?= set_value('rank',$customer_group[0]['rank']); ?>"
```

but I can't repopulate the checkbox

```
<?php if ($customer_group[0]['is_default'] == "1") echo "checked"; set_checkbox('is_default', '1'); ?>
```

The checkbox will check even I have not check it in the edit => fail to validate in the form, thanks for helping

**Update:**

Is it correct if change to :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['is_default']) || $customer_group[0]['is_default'] == "1"){
    echo "checked"; 
    }
    set_checkbox('is_default', '1'); 
 ?>
```

Comment: I would use a ternary operator for this instead of an if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple one just check for post data too if validation fails

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['is_default'])){
    echo "checked"; set_checkbox('is_default', '1');
    }elseif ($customer_group[0]['is_default'] == "1"){
    echo "checked"; set_checkbox('is_default', '1');
    }
 ?>
```

So if user checks checkbox and validation fails the form will have a checked check box as to save the choice made by user if there is no post data then it will be checked by database data that is in `$customer_group`

Comment: Thanks, is two condition same action ok ? echo "checked"; set_checkbox('is_default', '1');

Comment: @user782104 yes if post data contains `is_default` index it means user has checked checkbox

Comment: why not just  if(isset($_POST['is_default']) || ($customer_group[0]['is_default'] == "1")){ ?

Comment: @user782104 yes this one can also be a solution but i have tried to provide the answer in step wise like first look for post data if not the look for db data

Comment: should the set_checkbox('is_default', '1') set outside the condition?right now it seems it will not repopulate if there is invalid value before or has database value before. Thanks

Comment: @user782104 i am unable to get your point can you elaborate it more and if you put `set_checkbox` outbox then there is no sense to have a condition with empty body

Comment: @user782104 it doesn't make sense to me your code will always show checkbox as checked even there is no post data or database is there any problem to use my answer